# C++ OpenSSL EVP_DigestVerify intermittently failing rsa_pk1.c:103 with RSA_R_BAD_PAD_BYTE_COUNT

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

I have included [a full, basic code example](https://ideone.com/gFfSIr) which can be compiled with the following command (with boost installed) "g++ -std=c++11 -g test.cpp -lssl -lcrypto -lboost_system"

The code I have pretty closely follows the OpenSSL EVP Signing and Verifying [Asymmetric example](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying) with a bit of Boost refactoring for memory management.

However, it's behaviour is very intermittent and changes with different keys as well as different text. I am pretty sure I am missing something here but due to time pressures I am about to just make a secure system call to the openssl utility which I have had no issues with.

The test output below illustrates the issue. "A" and "AAA" are signed and verified successfully, whereas "AA" fails with a RSA_R_BAD_PAD_BYTE_COUNT padding error. In order to try an correct this, I set the padding to PKCS but it made no difference.

```
2048 bit [2] -  Text: A - Success
Authentication failure: 67567722, rsa_pk1.c, 103, , 0 257
Error string: error:0407006A:lib(4):func(112):reason(106)
2048 bit [2] -  Text: AA - Failure
2048 bit [2] -  Text: AAA - Success
```

Any pointers here would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: You will find a link on the first line to the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has to do with the way you're converting `char*` into `string` inside `testSignVerify`:

```
string hashString((char*)pHash.get());
```

should be:

```
string hashString(pHash.get(), hashLength);
```

It is because default string constructor will stop on the first `'\0'` it encounters, which is OK for normal strings, but for cryptographic hash it is just one of possible chars.